# Pre-roll html5 VAST

Tags: javascript, html, vast

I'm used to build Flash banners for some Pre-roll video in flash player but with the death of Flash i'm looking for another way to build my banner to make them work into a html5 player:

i read that it was possible to introduct JS into the vast to use some event like pause , stop , ... But i'd like to do more than just a click and even that i'd do not find any example of where i should put the JS into the Vast to make it read it , also if someone have an example of a working Vast with JS it would be great.

Here's an example of my actual VAST :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VAST version="2.0">
    <Ad id="pub_100">
        <InLine>
            <AdSystem>Pub VAST 2.0</AdSystem>
            <AdTitle></AdTitle>
            <Description></Description>
            <Error></Error> 
    <Impression><![CDATA[%%SERVER%%/RealMedia/ads/adstream_lx.ads/%%PAGE%%/%%RAND%%/%%POS%%/%%CAMP%%/%%IMAGE%%/%%USER%%?_RM_EMPTY_&%%QUERY%%]]></Impression>
       <Impression><![CDATA[http://openad.tf1.fr/RealMedia/ads/adstream.cap/%%RAND%%?c=billb&dv=1&date=1]]></Impression>
                    <Creatives>
                <Creative id="" sequence="">
                    <Linear>
                        <AdParameters><![CDATA[%%SERVER%%/RealMedia/ads/click_lx.ads/%%PAGE%%/%%RAND%%/%%POS%%/%%CAMP%%/[EVENTNAME]_%%ADID%%/%%USER%%?%%QUERY%%]]></AdParameters>
                        <Duration>00:00:21</Duration>
                        <VideoClicks>
                        <ClickThrough><![CDATA[%%SERVER%%/RealMedia/ads/click_lx.ads/%%PAGE%%/%%RAND%%/%%POS%%/%%CAMP%%/%%IMAGE%%/%%USER%%]]></ClickThrough>
                        </VideoClicks>
                        <MediaFiles>
                        <MediaFile delivery="progressive" type="video/x-flv" width="660" height="370" scalable="true" maintainAspectRatio="true"><![CDATA[http://slpubmedias.fr/ikea.swf]]></MediaFile>
                        </MediaFiles>

          </TrackingEvents>
                    </Linear>
                </Creative>
            </Creatives>
        </InLine>
    </Ad>
</VAST>
```

Comment: On https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/tags you can find more examples. If you are looking for interactivity of the ads, you should have a look into VPAID as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

To play a pre-roll (the context doesn't matter if the ad is not a companion or so) you need to have a vast complaint video player. It has to send a request to the Vast-Tag. The videoplayer reads all neccessary tracking information from that VAST. Inside of this vast you don't need a flash file (you just have a flash file) but a MediaFile which the html videoplayer can work with (mp4,webm, ogg, ...)